# How to choose the value and label from Django ModelChoiceField queryset

Tags: python, html, django, forms, model

I was trying to create a django form and one of my field contain a ModelChoiceField

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):

    person =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id'), required=False)
    age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=18, max_value=99, required=False)
```

When I try the code above what it return as an html ouput is

```
<option value="1">Person object</option>
```

on my Person Model I have the fields "id, fname, lname, is_active" . Is it possible to specify that my dropdown option will use "id" as the value and "lname" as the label? The expected html
should be

```
<option value="1">My Last Name</option>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Person model add:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{0}'.format(self.lname)
```

If you are using Python 3, then define `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return u'{0}'.format(self.lname)
```

Comment: Thanks! works for me. I just have an additional question which I have posted already above, does ModelChoiceField by default look for a certain column or field in the model that it uses as the label?

Comment: But this doesn't set the option value to a number, does it?

Comment: But what if you don't want the __unicode__. Can you tell it what to use?

Comment: @Sloy it only changes the way the instance is represented, in a readable way.

Answer (score 51):

You can just add a call to label_from_instance in the init of Form ie

by adding something like

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance

    @staticmethod
    def label_from_instance(obj):
        return "My Field name %s" % obj.name
```

Comment: Great elegant solution. gives you the ability to change select label of model for specific form.

Comment: This is a great solution because it allows you to use another label other than the string representation. Great!!!

Comment: Excellent!! This does exactly what's required without having to change the str representation permanently

Answer (score 36):

From the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

> The `__unicode__` (`__str__` on Python 3) method of the model will be
>   called to generate string representations of the objects for use in
>   the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass
>   ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will
>   receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for
>   representing it. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
>
> class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
>     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
>         return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
> ```

So, you can do that, or override `__str__` on your model class to return the last name.

Comment: Hello FogleBird, thanks for the response. This solution could actually work for me. I just have an additional question, is the django ModelChoiceField by default look for a certain column in a model to use as the label on the options?

Comment: The first thing it will look for is your __unicode__ def as defined in your model. Its __str__ in Python 3 as mentioned by FogleBird.

Comment: This answer pointed to the right direction, ModelChoiceField can be customized by providing arguments

Comment: How do you actually use this? Where do I put it, in the model or the form?

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite `label_from_instance` method of the `ModelChoiceField` instance to your custom method. You can do it inside the `__init__` method of the form

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    person =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id'), required=False)
    age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=18, max_value=99, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['person'].label_from_instance = lambda instance: instance.name
```

Answer (score 0):

to chose/change the value you can use "to_field_name" options ,
and to change the label of option you can overwrite the  "label_from_instance" function inside ModelChoiceField class,

and here is a simple example ,

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Group
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField


class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"My Object {obj.group_name}"


class MyPureDjangoForm(forms.Form):

    group = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                    widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                        'class': 'form-control'
                                    }),
                                    to_field_name='id',                                   
                                    
                                    )
```

for more information's kindly visit the following URL :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

i hope this helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642675/9566952), I recommend setting the `label_from_instance` method reference when creating the field. However, as I almost always want the model to have the same value for select field drop downs, I just define a `get_select_field_label()` method on the Model itself. This is especially useful when I want different select labels and `__str__()` representations. Heres a minimal example:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}, by {self.author.full_name}"

    def get_select_field_label(self):
        return f"{self.title}"


class BookForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label_from_instance = Book.get_select_field_label
```